# C Programing Boolean expression

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code in c programming prompting people to answer a boolean `yes` or `no` question then run the action accordingly. Instead of `IF` or `switch`.

```
include <stdlib.h>
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int children;
    int age;

    printf("please enter your age");
    scanf("%d", age);


    printf("are you married?, please enter y for Yes and n for No"\n\n);
    scanf("%s", mstatus);

    if (mstatus is y or Y)
    {
        printf("how many children do you have: \n\n")
        scanf("%d", children)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please go and re-read the basics. Your code is full of problems.

Comment: Quote: `Instead of IF or switch` ? Can you explain that a bit.

Comment: Indent your code. That's just one of many other problems.

Comment: How on earth did this get 2 upvotes?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", age);
```

should be :

```
scanf("%d", &age); // missing an ampersand here.
```

```
printf("are you married?, please enter y for Yes and n for No"\n\n);
```

to

```
printf("are you married?, please enter y for Yes and n for No\n\n"); // newlines should be inside the format string
```

Though the other answer addresses your issue, I believe using a `switch-case` is better here :

```
printf("are you married?, please enter y for Yes and n for No\n\n");
scanf("%c",&c);


switch(c)
{
 case('y'):
    printf("how many children do you have: \n\n");
    scanf("%d",&children); // Remember to put ampersand here
    break;
 case('n'):
    printf("Enjoy bachelorhood\n");
    break;
 default:
   printf("Choice neither y nor n, Confused about marriage?\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you sjsam. I saw some example with amplesand and tested this work as well. Does referencing to the variable makes any different?

Comment: You can use the variable as itself once is read. That is you need not do `printf("%c",&c)`. The right form is `printf("%c",c)`

Answer (score 1):

Although you have not described the specific problem you are facing, I think that I can help by making the following observations :

- First of all, `scanf()` needs to read a ***pointer*** in order to work.

  You have declared :

  ```
  int children;
  int age;
  ```

  so you need to modify your `scanf()` statements to :

  ```
  scanf("%d", &age);
  ```

  and

  ```
  scanf("%d", &children);
  ```

  accordingly.
- Moreover, the condition you use to check the answer needs modification too. Change it to :

  ```
  if (mstatus == 'y' || mstatus == 'Y')
  ```
- Also, change the following line :

  ```
  printf("are you married?, please enter y for Yes and n for No"\n\n);
  ```

  to :

  ```
  printf("are you married?, please enter y for Yes and n for No\n\n");
  ```

as you cannot have the newlines outside the quotation marks.

- Finally, the statements :

  ```
  printf("how many children do you have: \n\n")
  scanf("%d", children)
  ```

  both need a semicolon at the end in order to be valid, like this :

  ```
  printf("how many children do you have: \n\n");
  scanf("%d", children);
  ```

Comment: Thank you. May i know if there is such a thing as bool yes or no? if yes would bool better than if() or switch()?

Comment: @DerCha Do you mean `yes` or `no` as a value of a variable? If this is what you are asking, it does not exist. `Yes` and `no` are considered strings.